# Error installing Coro in Perl

Tags: perl, cpan

I have trouble with installing Coro module.

```
.......
                                              ^
dmake:  Error code 129, while making 'State.o'
dmake.exe:  Error code 255, while making 'subdirs'
  MLEHMANN/Coro-6.43.tar.gz
  C:\STRAWB~1\c\bin\dmake.exe -- NOT OK
Stopping: 'install' failed for 'M/ML/MLEHMANN/Coro-6.43.tar.gz'.
```

Full install log is here: [log](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=B4dn6BeF)

Comment: Looks like your error is simialr to this one on CPAN testers http://www.cpantesters.org/cpan/report/b02f5668-6c71-1014-8b3b-24dbe730af8d . I noticed you selected the 'f' option, but they recommend 'a' for Strawberry Perl.

Comment: Some of those errors are due to Coro's reliance on Perl internals. I'm guessing you used perl 5.22, and it hasn't been updated for 5.22 yet. The author is notoriously difficult to work with, and he doesn't use a bug tracker, so you'll need to contact him to see if he's aware of the problem and what his plans are.

Comment: Looks like issues are being addressed here https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Dist/Display.html?Name=Coro, you could raise another.

Comment: Someone got sufficiently frustrated with Coro & perl 5.22/5.24 to [publish a blog post about it](http://blogs.perl.org/users/aristotle/2016/05/coro-vs-5022.html).

Answer (score 0):

[Version 6.46](https://metacpan.org/changes/distribution/Coro) reports that it "restore[s] portability to perls with windows fork emulation".  That means Strawberry Perl.  It may solve your problem.